# Unable to get the Login user Email using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, jsom

I am trying to fetch the login user "**Email**" with below simple code, but finding no luck. 
Can any one help me in sorting out this problem.

```
<script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/spjs-utility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getUser
{
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 

web = context.get_web(); 

this._currentUser = web.get_currentUser(); 

context.load(this._currentUser); 

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod)); 
} 

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) 
{ 
alert(this._currentUser.get_title()); 
alert(this._currentUser.get_email()); 
} 
function onFaiureMethod(sender, args) 
{ 
alert('request failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
} 

</script>
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: I recommend using an JS IDE for formatting, linting and syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get current logged user details by calling following `init()` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
    document.getElementById('userId').innerHTML = currentUser.get_id();
    document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title();
    document.getElementById('userEmail').innerHTML = currentUser.get_email(); // Email
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
<div>Current Logged User:
    <span id="userLoginName"></span>
    <span id="userId"></span>
    <span id="userTitle"></span>
    <span id="userEmail"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid that's why you are not getting email and title of the user.

- `()` is missing in `getUser` function.
- You have not called `getUser` function. You need to call it after `sp.js` is loaded.

## Modified code

```
function getUser() {
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    web = context.get_web();

    this._currentUser = web.get_currentUser();

    context.load(this._currentUser);

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
}

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
    alert(this._currentUser.get_title());
    alert(this._currentUser.get_email());
}

function onFaiureMethod(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getUser);
```